# Convert time to float

Tags: objective-c, time, floating-point

What would be the best algorithm / code to convert time to float? I'm doing this in Obj-c but really all I need is an algorithm and I can make the code from there.

EX:

- **1:30am** to **1.50**
- **2:15pm** to **14.25**
- **5:45pm** to **17.75**

EDIT:
My time format is minutes since midnight.

Comment: What format is your time in? `NSDate`? `NSDateComponents`? `NSTimeInterval`?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII well my time is actually in minutes since midnight but I can get it to  any time format.

Comment: @Computer He meant to ask in what format you are receiving the time. Is it simply a string, or are you getting an actual `NSDate` object? But, looks like you've already accepted an answer, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the string to get two `int` numbers and an `am/pm` part (`h`, `m`, and `a`), and then calculate the fraction as follows:

```
int h, m, a;
// set a to 0 for "am", or 1 for "pm"
float time = 60*(a*12+h)+m;
float res = time / 60.0;
```

Comment: actually just the last part of that will work. It has been such a long day!!! dividing the minutes since midnight by 60.0 will convert it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

How about NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate?  And divide by 3600, of course.

Or, for time within a single day, use NSDateFormatter with an "A" date format to produce milliseconds since midnight, then mash on that.